# how to add tablelayout dynamically

Tags: android

I am creating an application that needs `TableLayout` . I have done my coding with `LinearLayout` and it is working but i am not able to use `TableLayout` in my project .i am getting an error of `NullPoinerException` in `logcat` . So please give me some solution how to add `TableLayout` dynamically.
thank u

```
public class player_name extends Activity {


LinearLayout player_name;
TableLayout ply_name = new TableLayout(this);
Bundle b,b1;




List<TextView> allEds = new ArrayList<TextView>();
List<Button> allplus = new ArrayList<Button>();
List<Button> allminus = new ArrayList<Button>();
List<EditText> alledit = new ArrayList<EditText>();
List<TextView> alltotal = new ArrayList<TextView>();
//List<TableRow> allrow = new ArrayList<TableRow>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.player_name);



    //b = getIntent().getExtras();
    //String resStr = b.getString("name");
    b1 = getIntent().getExtras();
    String[] result = b1.getStringArray("playerName");


    player_name = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.player_name);

    TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams=new TableLayout.LayoutParams 
            (TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1.0f);


    TextView[] ed1 = new TextView[result.length+1];
    Button[] plus = new Button[result.length+1];
    Button[] minus = new Button[result.length+1];
    EditText[] point = new EditText[result.length+1];
    TextView[] total = new TextView[result.length+1];
    TableRow[] TR= new TableRow[result.length+1];


    Button btnResult = new Button(player_name.this);
    btnResult.setText(" click here to get RESULT");






    for(int i=0;i<=(result.length-1);i++)
    {

        ed1[i] = new TextView(player_name.this);
        plus[i] = new Button(player_name.this);
        minus[i] = new Button(player_name.this);
        point[i] = new EditText(player_name.this);
        total[i] = new TextView(player_name.this);
        TR[i] = new TableRow(player_name.this);



        allEds.add(ed1[i]);
        alltotal.add(total[i]);
        alledit.add(point[i]);
        allplus.add(plus[i]);
        allminus.add(minus[i]);
        //allrow.add(TR[i]);




        TR[i].addView(ed1[i]);
        TR[i].addView(plus[i]);
        TR[i].addView(minus[i]);
        TR[i].addView(point[i]);
        TR[i].addView(total[i]);

        ply_name.addView(TR[i]);
        TR[i].setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);

        player_name.addView(ply_name);





        ed1[i].setId(i);
        ed1[i].setHeight(50);
        ed1[i].setWidth(300);
        ed1[i].setText(result[i]);
        ed1[i].setTextColor(Color.CYAN);



        total[i].setId(i);
        total[i].setHeight(50);
        total[i].setWidth(300);
        total[i].setText(""+0);
        total[i].setTextColor(Color.CYAN);


        point[i].setId(i);
        point[i].setHeight(50);
        point[i].setWidth(300);
        //point[i].setText(Integer.parseInt("0"));
        point[i].setHint("enter\t"+result[i]+"\'s\tpoint");
        point[i].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        point[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);



        plus[i].setId(i);
        plus[i].setHeight(50);
        plus[i].setWidth(300);
        plus[i].setText("+");
        plus[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);



        minus[i].setId(i);
        minus[i].setHeight(50);
        minus[i].setWidth(300);
        minus[i].setText("-");
        minus[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    }

    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    player_name.addView(btnResult, lp);


    btnResult.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(player_name.this,result.class);
            startActivity(intent1);

        }
    });





}

}
```

Comment: Just post the logcat trace in the post!

Comment: What code are you using for `TableLayout`.?? and post your LogCat.

Answer (score -1):

put this part of code:

```
ply_name = new TableLayout(this);
```

in the `onCreate()` method. and just define:

```
TableLayout ply_name;
```

as the member of the class.

Comment: @WilsonS if it is working then it would be kind of you to mark it as the accepted answer! :)